# If checkbox checked enable input field in a loop

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Okay, firstly i have a MySQL result in a loop.

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET" name="myform">

<table id="matrix" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th width="5%"></th>
  <th width="5%">ID</th>
  <th width="25%">Name</th>
  <th width="15%">price</th>
  <th width="15%">count</th>
  <th width="5%">Link</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr id="noresults">
  <td align="center" colspan="6"><h3>No results</h3></td>
 </tr>

<?
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $html  = "<tr>";
        $html .= "<th><input class='ads_Checkbox' type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['pro_name']."' onclick='myFunction()'> </th>";
        $html .= "<th>".$row['pro_id']."</th>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_name']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td><input type='number' name='prices[]' id='price' value='".$row['pro_price']."' disabled></td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_category']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_link']."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";
        echo $html;
    }?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="order"></textarea>
</form>
```

What i want when i ckecked a checkbox:

- set the input field attributes to 'enabled' (document.getElementById("price").disabled=this.checked;)
- get the input field value and save it somewhere in the page

Here's my javascript code

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var products = document.forms[1];
            var txt = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].checked) {
                    txt = txt + products[i].value + ", ";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("order").value = "" + txt;
            document.getElementById("price").disabled=this.checked;
        }
</script>
```

The show tag is here a  (now it's wrong).
It's working now with a simple line, but when i checked a second or third line checkbox, the first line's input do what i want. :(

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send the checked object in the dynamically created HTML :

```
      ....   

        $counter = 0; 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                   $counter++;
                    $html  = "<tr>";
                    $html .= "<th><input class='ads_Checkbox' type='checkbox' name='products[]' value='".$row['pro_name']."'
     onclick='myFunction(this,". $counter .")'> </th>"; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<< send the clicked checkbox to the function
                    $html .= "<th>".$row['pro_id']."</th>";
                    $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_name']."</td>";
                    $html .= "<td><input type='number' name='prices[]' 
id='price_" . $counter ."' value='".$row['pro_price']."' disabled></td>";
                    $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_category']."</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>".$row['pro_link']."</td>";
                    $html .= "</tr>";
                    echo $html;
                }?>

        ....
```

Then fix your js to become compatible

```
<script>
        function myFunction(checkbox, level) { // <<<< add the checkbox as paremeter as well as the level (obtained via php counter)
            var products = document.forms[1];
            var txt = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                if (products[i].checked) {
                    txt = txt + products[i].value + ", ";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("order").value = "" + txt;
            document.getElementById("price_" + level).disabled=checkbox.checked; // check if it is checked and assign the value
        }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I have added a counter at PHP level where I give each price a unique ID price_1, price_2...etc The passed this counter to the js function from PHP, and within js concatenated the counter to the id to obtain the right element.

Comment: I think it's a good start with a counter and this code is almost perfect to me, because i understand how it's work. But here's another problem...when checked the checkbox the input field attribute is disabled, when unchecked the checkbox the input field turn to enabled. I want the opposite version. Tried so many options. example: if(document.getElementById("price_" + level).checked = false)document.getElementById("price_" + level).disabled=true;}else {document.getElementById("price_" + level).disabled=false;
   } This code don't work at the moment, i'm working on it. :)

Comment: the price is an input field and not a checkbox you cannot use `.checked` with it. If you want the opposite, you can just use the negation `!checkbox.checked` on the same line so it becomes `document.getElementById("price_" + level).disabled=!(checkbox.checked);` this will enable/disable the price in an opposite manner of the checkbox

Comment: Simple and great. Thanks, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You get duplicate id `price` in input, so it only find the first `input` to enable/disable.
2. `this` is bind to `window`. You still can use window.event.target to get the target.

You can change you function to:

```
function myFunction(checkbox) { // <<<< add the checkbox as paremeter

  var products = document.forms[1];
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      if (products[i].checked) {
          txt = txt + products[i].value + ", ";
      }
  }


  document.getElementById("order").value = "" + txt;
  // Get the checkbox clicked.
  var checkbox = window.event.target;
  // strucutre is tr -> td -> checkbox and tr -> td -> input, so up trace twice to get tr.
  var tr = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;
  // Get the related input. and set value
  var input = tr.querySelector("input");
  input.disabled=checkbox.checked; // check if it is checked and assign the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right the duplicated input id isn't good. :) I tried your version, but because i'm just study JS i don't understand the whole code. I need to read after a few things. (example window.event.target)

Comment: No problem! window.event is the current event when you click on that checkbox, and it'll store the trigger (in other words, the clicked `checkbox`) in window.event.target. And it's always better to use KAD's answer by create and retireve that unique id when doing things.